# Custom position for Street View "close" button

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I can enable/disable the Close-button like so: `enableCloseButton: true`
AFAIK there are no options to position this control anywhere but the default top-right.

The docs don't give much detail on this particular issue:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#StreetViewControls

Is my only option to create a custom control? Seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own button and on click call

```
map.getStreetView().setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

CSS

```
.btn {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="closeStreetView" class="btn">Click me</button>
```

Javascript

```
var closeButton = document.querySelector('#closeStreetView'),
controlPosition = google.maps.ControlPosition[config.streetViewCloseButtonLocation];
var streetView = map.getStreetView();
    streetView.setOptions({ enableCloseButton: false });
    streetView.controls[ controlPosition ].push( closeButton );
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(closeButton, 'click', function(){
    streetView.setVisible(false);
```